# Нужно ли обособлять конструкции с "посредством"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять конструкцию "посредством политики нулевого ковида"?

Сейчас рубль вырос благодаря сочетанию нескольких событий, которое не сможет длиться вечно. Тем временем, Китай посредством политики нулевого ковида искусственно замедлял свою экономику – и выйдет из ипотечного кризиса, всего лишь отказавшись от этой политики.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не нужно. А кроме того, не нужно обособлять словосочетание «тем временем» (оно никогда не бывало вводным) и оборот с ЧАСТИЦЕЙ «всего лишь»))

Comment: Разве конструкция "всего лишь отказавшись от этой политики" - это не деепричастный оборот?

Comment: Необязательно: не всё, что окружает деепричастие, является деепричастым оборотом.